# Create From/To Pairs by sequential date R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which lists a grouping value, a code, and the date the code occurred.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  Type = c(
    "H08", "C42", "J02", "H03", "D44", "D05", "D81", "Q11", "S02",
    "Q04", "H81", "D06", "F08", "E82", "D03", "Q82", "Q13", "S01",
    "E05", "E10", "H01", "E82", "E01"
  ),
  Unit = c(
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
  ),
  DATE = as.Date(c(
    "2015-08-20", "2015-10-06", "2015-10-26", "2015-11-13", "2016-03-26",
    "2016-06-03", "2016-06-13", "2016-09-22", "2017-03-16", "2017-06-15",
    "2018-08-29", "2018-08-31", "2018-10-09", "2020-04-20", "2020-05-06",
    "2020-05-06", "2020-05-06", "2020-08-19", "2016-11-03", "2016-11-03",
    "2017-05-05", "2017-05-08", "2020-05-06"
  ))
```

I want to convert this into From:To pairs within each group based on time, with the caveat that sometimes there are more than one to or more than one from.

So looking at the first few rows in the example data,

```
   Type  Unit  DATE      
   <chr> <chr> <date>    
 1 H08   A     2015-08-20
 2 C42   A     2015-10-06
 3 J02   A     2015-10-26
 4 H03   A     2015-11-13
```

The output I am aiming to achieve is

```
Unit From To
A    H08  C42
A    C42  J02
A    J02  H03
```

The only complication is in cases where there are multiple Type on the same date

```
14 E82   A     2020-04-20
15 D03   A     2020-05-06
16 Q82   A     2020-05-06
17 Q13   A     2020-05-06
18 S01   A     2020-08-19
```

Where the output should be

```
A E82 D03
A E82 Q82
A E82 Q13
A D03 S01
A Q82 S01
A Q13 S01
```

My preferred method would be using dplyr pipes if possible.

I'm trying to get something going with reframe() and add_rows(), but currently can't think my way through what I'd need to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent update to dplyr adds `join_by()` and `closest()` to the join functions, which allows us to do a "rolling join." That allows us to grab the first row where the date in table 2 is later than the date in table 1: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html#rolling-joins

```
# edit -- original worked ok b/c data was grouped by Unit, added Unit as 
#         join key to work otherwise too.

library(dplyr) #v1.1.0
df %>%
  left_join(df, join_by(Unit, closest(DATE < DATE)), multiple = "first") %>%
  select(Unit, Type.x, Type.y)


# A tibble: 23 × 3
# Groups:   Unit [2]
   Unit  Type.x Type.y
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
 1 A     H08    C42   
 2 A     C42    J02   
 3 A     J02    H03   
 4 A     H03    D44   
 5 A     D44    D05   
 6 A     D05    D81   
 7 A     D81    Q11   
 8 A     Q11    S02   
 9 A     S02    Q04   
10 A     Q04    H81   
# … with 13 more rows
```